# How to use class methods instead of functions in Bottle microframework?

Tags: python, bottle

I am trying to use methods of my own class instead of funcons.
But ths code fails due to "syntax error". What am i doing wrong?

```
from bottle import route, run, template

class controller():

    def test(self):
        return ("<h1>Its a main page!</h1>")

    def hello(self,name):
        return "Hello {0}".format(name)


sc = controller()

@route('/test')
sc.test()

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)


@route('/')
def indexFunc():
    return ('<h1>Hello on first App!!</h1>!')



run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: I assume by "class methods" you mean "methods", and not python's @classmethod ?

Answer (score 1):

`sc.test()` returns a string. You can't decorate a string. So the first problem is, you are *calling* that method (and therefore trying to decorate its result) instead of decorating the method itself.

The second problem is that the `@` decorator syntax must be followed by a function definition, i.e., a `def` keyword. You could write a function that does nothing but call `sc.test()`, as [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36070048/416467) by llyas. Or you can take advantage of the fact that the `@` is simply syntactic sugar for a function call, and just write:

```
route('/test')(sc.test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot decorate a function call, you decorate a function definition. 
Try replacing this line:

```
sc.test()
```

wiith this:

```
@route('/test')
def view():
    return sc.test()
```